# When Hibernate org.hibernate.StaleStateException comes?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am getting org.hibernate.StaleStateException.

When can this exception come in hibernate ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use  getSession().save(obj); try changing to it with getSession().saveOrUpdate(obj);. That should save your object when it doesn't exist and update it (to not have the overlarge field) when it does.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Thrown when a version number or timestamp check failed, indicating
>   that the Session contained stale data (when using long transactions
>   with versioning). Also occurs if we try delete or update a row that
>   does not exist.
>
> Note that this exception often indicates that the user failed to
>   specify the correct unsaved-value strategy for a class!

Look at [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/StaleStateException.html).

Answer (score 0):

Other than the good reason, i.e. there are actually two threads/users working concurrently on the same data, in my experience this can happen if the application merges detached entities without taking into account that, in this case, `session.merge(entity)` returns a new entity instance (that has the updated version/timestamp).

If the application does not let the original entity instance be garbage collected, it may be used again in a subsequent update call, effectively attempting to update the persistence layer with stale data (data that are versioned earlier than the persistent copy).